# Android application versions

Tags: android, sdk, version

I am new to Android and I created an application with API 16 and Minimum SDK 16 and I have a slide animation between two activities which works only on version 16 minimum. So on my device Galaxy S2 it works fine but when I tried it on Galaxy S1 the API supported is 10 so the animation can't work. I don't really know should I just give up on that animation or is there a way to keep it working on both devices. I guess that once my app will be launched on the market it should be supported by both devices and also others so it would be nice if I could make it work on multiple devices.

Here is the code for XML animation file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<translate 
xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; 
android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
```

And here is the code in Activity:

```
Bundle bndlanimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation( getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2).toBundle(); startActivity(slideactivity,bndlanimation)";
```

its a code which helps me make an effect for which when moving the second activity the screen moves to left.

Can I get help or advice?

Comment: Also i forgot to mention Galaxy S1 /Android 2.3.6 i guess doesn't support action bar and i really need it in my app

Comment: can you add you .xml animation and the folders that you are used

Comment: For Action Bar i recommend [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), but android has its own support library : ) [SupportLibrary](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

Comment: What do you mean by "slide animation"?

Comment: @AhmedMontasserRossafi  Typically better if you put the code as an edit / update in your post above.  Any code in the comments however can be provided in code text by surrounding them with the '`' or '~' key in the upper left of the keyboard.

Comment: @AhmedMontasserRossafi add them in your post not as comment ;)

Comment: okay thank you @JaySnayder  i'll do it . Thanks Abdellah too

Comment: Thanks very much @shawty i was in such a hury i did terrible mistakes

Answer (score 0):

As a developer I don't bother to support before API 15 anymore, or 16 as you have come across.  At some point, you need to design for current operating systems.  Gingerbread is still out there, but there certainly are not any modern devices supporting it.  The S2 is a considerably old device.  Unless you are purposefully aiming at older systems I would consider not backwards supporting to 10 anymore.  It's tough to know when to move forward, and this will differ on a case by case basis.

If you want further input however on why the slide animations are not working that you have written in perhaps an animation xml file, then if you could provide the code we could assist further.  There certainly should be a way to implement the transitions you want without relying upon OS specific classes.

ActionBar as you have mentioned above as well as perhaps some additional features are available with the support libraries that Android provides.  Including the latest support libraries can provide access to ActionBar similar schemes as well as even some other later released code.

Comment: Yes exactly i developped it for API 16 and more , including from Jelly Bean to Kitkat and more but i just thought before launching it on market , and if some people out on the world have a Samsung Young or Ace or S1 device?

Comment: @AhmedMontasserRossafi They will never see it on the store.  It won't be available to them.  So you will never run into an issue.  The store restricts this for you.

Comment: Ahh so the store makes it available only for phones having exact API number or more in my app . Thanks so much it my first time and I wasn't aware of that

Comment: here is the code for my xml animation file :



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"/>


and then i use Bundle 

Bundle bndlanimation = ActivityOptions.makeCustomAnimation(      getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animation,      R.anim.animation2).toBundle();
startActivity(slideactivity,bndlanimation);